# wordpress: wp_list_categories order by is not working at all

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories, jigoshop

**Context: Using Wordpress with jigoshop plugin**

I am using wp_list_categories to bring product categories that working well and brings the required list. The only problem is the ordering of the categories. I have used several orderby options (name, ID, slug) but the list order remains still the same as follows:

Tools & Brushes
Makeup Remover & Primer
Powder
Lips
Highlighter
Foundation
Eyes
Concealer
Bronzer
Blush

The jigoshop widget has following code:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'show_count'    => $count,
    'hierarchical'  => $is_hierarchial,
    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
    'title_li'      => null,
);
wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_product_categories_args', $args));
```

I am going to replace it by adding filter:

```
add_filter('widget_product_categories_args','myFun');
function myFun($out){
    .......
    .......
    $args = array(
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'style'              => 'list',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'child_of'           => $topMostParent,
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'title_li'           => '',
    'current_category'   => $cur_cat,
    'taxonomy'           => $taxonomyName,
);  
return $args;
}
```

I have tried by deactivating other plugins too but got no effect on result. Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: have you put a `die('Check');` in the function to check if the function is executed?

Comment: yes function is executing. I have been checking $args value through      var_dump($args) in that function.

Comment: `var_dump` the outcome of the `apply_filters` that way you at least will it actually pass that value or if it is over written, After that try passion a high prio like 999999

Comment: I had already tried var_dump in myFun to see the $args values they were showing the changes i made. I used this commend to see the apply_filter `var_dump(apply_filters('widget_product_categories_args', $args));` and it shows the updated values in the array.

Interestingly i have tried this command instead just to check:
    `wp_list_categories('show_count=0&title_li=&depth=0&orderby=name&taxonomy=product_cat&child_of=44&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0');`

But no effect on ordering.

Comment: mhhh... does order `ASC` / `DESC` have any visible effect?

Comment: everything does effect but the order options. ASC/DESC also doesn't put any effect on it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely,
Somewhere another filter is changing the arguments these can be.
In order they are executed:

- `get_categories_taxonomy`
- `get_terms_args`
- `get_terms`
- `get_terms_orderby`  **<-- most likely?**
- `list_terms_exclusions`
- `get_terms_fields`
- `terms_clauses`
- `get_terms` *(again)*
- `get_terms` *(again again)*
- `wp_list_categories`

These are divided over 3 primary functions ( functions which are likely to affect the outcome)

- `wp_list_categories`

  - `get_categories`

    - `get_terms`

I suggest starting with the `get_terms_orderby` filter.

If that doesn't work I would try to use the function [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)
That way you will at least know if at which level it goes wrong.

Hopes this helps, let me know ;)